# How to get pointcut for system library class initialization

Tags: java, android, aspectj

I would like to intercept the link passed to `HttpGet()`.

In my aspect class, I tried to use the following code for pointcut

```java
@Pointcut("call(* org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.new(..))")
public void httpGet(){}
```

However, this doesn't work and even will block my other pointcuts and interceptions.

So I'm wondering what's the correct way to intercept the initialization of system library classes?

Comment: Remove the duplicate `org.apache`?

Comment: Thanks, it's a typo. The actual code doesn't have this duplicate.

Comment: Whyt kind of answer do you expect with so little information? Would you please not just show us your pointcut but also the advice and the code you want to intercept? Give us a full picture, please do not keep people who wnat to help you guessing.

Comment: Unless the approach you are trying to use gets in between the code you are planning to write and the android execution environment, I doubt this will work, as most system libraries are pre-loaded into the execution environment (VM and its native bypasses) *before* a single line of your code ever executes.