# How to create pointcut for inline generated initialized of class (logger of lombok)

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop, lombok

I have this class need to be proxied

```
public class A {
   private static final Logger b = LoggerFactory.createLogger(A.class)
   public void doSth() {
     b.debug("something to log)"
   }
}
```

So i want to wrap logger b to do some dynamic config before and after log is executed.

why i need to do it:

- i need to change appender config base on dynamic property (different per request
- logger is used many places in project
- they're generated by @Slf4j(lombok) so i can not wrap it manually like: Logger b = LoggerFactoryProxy.createLogger(A.class)

Can anyone know how to define pointcut to match this inline generated code?

I'm using spring aop

Thanks

Comment: may be i should use call expression, but poor me, call is not supported in spring-aop, reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843051/how-to-get-pointcut-for-system-library-class-initialization

Comment: Please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60784365/4214241 . I assume this is what you are looking for

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. Please show in sample code what you mean by _"change appender config based on dynamic property"_. And what do you mean by _"logger **is** used many places"_? One logger is used in many places or rather different loggers are used, one per annotated class?

Comment: hi @kriegaex my project is multitenant which serve for many country, one web application for 10 countries, then if in code i only use log.info("blah blah"), i will have a huge log file  (~100k request/ hour) and impossible to trace issue if any. so i want to separate log per country by using SiftingAppender (slf4j), that appender allow to receive MDC context which has dynamic key.

Comment: depend on country (come from session) i can put country-key to MDC and SiftingAppender will log to corressponding file, example: vn-app.log, id-app.log, jp-app.log...it's more easier to trace issue

Comment: Wow, you answer after 4 months of inactivity. The problem does not seem to have been urgent. Anyway, thanks for the feedback. But I cannot debug abstract prose. I much prefer sample code, ideally an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hi @kriegaex in fact, i've found another solution by using Proxy pattern of java. i'm use org.reflections library to scan all classes at start time then replace generated logger with proxied one. then it work as expected

Comment: but i'm still waiting for a better solution form you @kriegaex :)

Comment: And I am still waiting for more information from you. ;-) BTW, I saw you use AspectJ in other questions you asked. Why do you need a proxy here? Are you restricted to Spring AOP in this project somehow? Would normal AspectJ (no proxies) not be sufficient?

Comment: @kriegaex i will provide MVCE soon in this post